# Calculus in supporting a dome over a pillar of certain height/ Calculus in Dome Making

Tags: calculus

I am trying to model a dome over a pillar using calculus. I need some help with the ways I can do so because currently, I can't figure out how to integrate calculus in this.

Comment: Do you have a picture of the case? Any equations? What is it exactly (mathematically - meaning that I'm asking you to show the equations) that you're trying to do?

Comment: I have a situation that I want to solve using math, but I cant figure out exactly what math to use to do this. My situation is, I have a dome of a volume 1500 cubic meters. This dome will be fixed atop a hall. The hall can be thought of as a single pillar supporting the dome. If I have one of the variables for the pillar such as height or the radius of the pillar, how can I find out the volume of the pillar that will be required to support the dome?